# GridView dynamic column binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with a dropdownlist in the header for selecting which column of my datasource should be displayed.

ASP:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvProperties" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="part_id" DataSourceID="edsPartProperties" 
        AllowSorting="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="propertyname" HeaderText="propertyname" 
                SortExpression="propertyname" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="value_num" HeaderText="value_num" 
                SortExpression="value_num" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="value_char" HeaderText="value_char" 
                SortExpression="value_char" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="symbol" HeaderText="symbol" 
                SortExpression="symbol" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGvColumn" runat="server" 
                        onselectedindexchanged="ddlGvColumn_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                        AutoPostBack="true" onprerender="ddlGvColumn_PreRender">
                    <asp:ListItem>Value</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Identifier</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Eval(((DropDownList)(this.gvProperties.HeaderRow.FindControl("ddlGvColumn"))).SelectedValue) %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

This works fine for the first time it is loaded!
As soon as i select an other item from the dropdownlist, the gridview loads the first item again.
So i decided to store the ViewState and re-set the the dropdownlist at onprerender. So now the dropdownlist shows the correct selected item, but the lables in the itemtamplate do not bind to it!

Here the code for the 2 events:

```
protected void ddlGvColumn_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    DropDownList ddlProps = (DropDownList)sender;
    ViewState["selVal"] = ddlProps.SelectedValue;

}
protected void ddlGvColumn_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    DropDownList ddlProps = (DropDownList)sender;
    foreach (ListItem li in ddlProps.Items) {
        if (li.Value.Equals(ViewState["selVal"])) {
            li.Selected = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get the Items in the Column bound to the selected value in the header?
e: fireing databind on the gridview in the SelectedIndexChanged method doesn't work either

Comment: What does your page load block look like?

Comment: my page_load block is empty

Comment: binding the column items to the value of a dropdownlist OUTSIDE the gridview works. but thats not really what i want to do!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create a `global variable` that will hold the value you selected from the dropdown list. Place the initialization of the `global variable` in `SelectedIndexChanged`. Then you can put the value of the `global variable` in a condition to set the selected item of the dropdown list. You can put this condition in `PreRender` event.